# pe:imageAreaSelect Primefaces imageareaselect highlight programmatically

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I would like to be able to hightlight an image and save the highlight coordinates to the database. When I reopen the image, I want to read the highlighted coordinates from the database and programatically re-highlight image.

I can get the coordinates and store them using this example:

```
<pe:imageAreaSelect id="areaSelect" for="imgView" handles="true" show="#{imagesBean.hasHighlight}">
  <p:ajax event="selectEnd" listener="#{imagesBean.areaSelectListener}" delay="200" />
</pe:imageAreaSelect>
```

My challenge is trying to apply the highlight (areaselection) programatically when I reload the image. While the `show="#{imagesBean.hasHighlight}"` attribute does show the highlighting (grey overlay), I cannot find a way to feed the coordinates into it.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I went through the attributes from the documentation. Its my first time working with primefaces-extensions, let me try view the javascript code

Comment: I checked the Java code for ImageAreaSelect, I dont see anything that accepts the coordinates. I have opted to manipulate the original image in 'areaSelectListener' i.e draw ractangles on the image and reload the manipulated image. This works fine for my purpose but if there is a way to programatically do the highlighting, please advise.

Comment: Thanks @Kukeltje. Using javascript setSelection and update() worked.

Comment: You are welcome. Answer created, please accept it. And for your info, I did not know anything about this component, never used it. But looking at the source is soooo powerful.

Comment: Well when you said javascript I got lost. I still need to understand how the components are designed. I get the ImageAreaSelect.java and its associated renderer class but was not aware of any associated javascript. Any references to quickly get an understanding would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost each PrimeFaces and PrimeFaces Extensions component consists of java classes, javascript and css.

If you start at the main sources e.g. for PrimeFaces Extensions in github, https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/tree/master/src/main, the following stucture applies:

- component classes: [/java/org/primefaces/extensions/component/<component>](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/tree/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/extensions/component)
- javascript: [resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces-extensions/<component>](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces-extensions/)
- css: [resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces-extensions/<component>](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces-extensions/)

The latter two are the same for PrimeFaces Extensions, but for PrimeFaces they differ, but you'll get the picture. Components often use generic and sometime specific classes in the packages above, but those are kind of self-descriptive.

If you now take a look at the javascript in [1-imageareaselect.js](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces-extensions/imageareaselect/1-imageareaselect.js), you see there is

```
setSelection : function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    this.instance.setSelection(x1, y1, x2, y2);
},
```

You can use that and call that on the widgetVar. To get this info to the client when loading the page should be a no-brainer. The comment above te function says to make the setting of the selection visible call

```
update()
```

on the widgetVar after setting the selection.